# How to convert date/time string into minutes since Unix epoch?

Tags: java, date

I need to convert date/time in a text file into number of minutes elapsed since unix epoch (i.e., January 1st, 1970):

```
e.g. 2006-01-01 07:14:38.000 into 18934874
```

I'm using Java to parse the file.
thanks

Comment: *Minutes*, are you sure? 3 249 834 224 378 minutes = 6 178 993.91 years. You probably mean milliseconds, although the example in your question isn't quite right even then.

Comment: (A timestamp, milliseconds since epoch, corresponding to 2006-01-01 would be around 1136092440000. That in minutes would be ~ 18934874.)

Comment: @Jonik Correct, sorry the number is wrong

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can use the class SimpleDateFormat to parse the time. For example

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdf.parse("2006-01-01 07:14:38.000");
long timeInMillisSinceEpoch = date.getTime(); 
long timeInMinutesSinceEpoch = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillisSinceEpoch);
```

### disclaimer

1. A few minutes ago I realized that I've used the wrong pattern for milliseconds (used 's' instead of 'S'). Sorry for the mistake.
2. Added suggestion from @superfav

Comment: Since Java 5, You can use `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillisSinceEpoch);` to avoid the _magic number_.

Comment: do we need to divide here to convert to minutes, it seems the alternative answer to this is  `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeInMillisSinceEpoch)`. Can you update your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Neeraj looks like I botched the edit.